# I don't like [u]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

A [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/71363/33972) was tagged with the single letter [u](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/u). This is the only question with this tag, the tag name has no intrinsic meaning and is probably a typo, and the tag's wiki is empty/nonexistent. Can we nuke [u](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/u)?

Comment: Agreed. I've removed the tag

Comment: However, [u] *loves* you.

Comment: Note that if a tag becomes orphaned (no question uses it) for long enough, it will get [deleted by the system automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/231379). So typo tags like this do go away on their own, once the typo is fixed.